# wordpress development on linux and deployment to windows server

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Will I have problems doing wordpress development on my linux laptop and then deploying the finished site to a windows server, i.e. will there be any code differences in the site code between linux and windows (the wordpress stuff) and/or problems between MySQL on the to differing platforms.  Anybody done this before? ... any problems?

( I don't do development on a windows platform .. preference is linux and don't want to do the development on the production server ... or buy a windows machine)

Thanks,

Carl

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be too many issues.  Be wary of file-system access though -- there are a few differences.  Look at this example from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).  Being a Linux user, you can probably see how this could cause problems, even with relative paths.

```
$handle = fopen("c:\\folder\\resource.txt", "r");
```

For the MySQL, I recommend writing a very simple request and just var_dump the results.  Once you have that working, copy the settings to your WordPress config.

Depending on your server software, you could have some problematic differences.  A major one is `mod_rewrite` which Apache has, and I make frequent use of.  I think WordPress uses it too so URLs will look cleaner.  When you go from Linux to Windows you may find 404 errors, or PHP errors surrounding this.  Most Windows servers have an alternative so it depends on your server software.

If I notice anything else, I'll add it here.

Comment: FakeRainBrigand, Thanks for your input ... yup, you're right.  There are some gotcha's in there!  The best way to do this is probably the sledge-hammer approach ... just do it somewhere its safe and see if it burps.